# What does a transistor do?

Tags: transistors

Let's say I have a regular motor circuit using an arduino. The motor is a standard motor with a motor controller and I connect it to my arduino and get the code working but I realize that the motor is going a little slow.

If I add a transistor to the circuit the right way, does that make my motor run faster or does it not have any effect at all?

Comment: Usually a transistor, along with some resistors, is just a switch to on/off the motor. Is that your purpose?

Comment: Your motor controller **is** a bunch of transistors.

Comment: I may be missing something, but what is a "standard motor" for you? A DC motor? Since it has a controller, then is it perhaps a stepper motor or AC motor?

Comment: So what I want to do with the resistor is to have an input current/ voltage from the arduino. And use a transistor to apmlify either the voltage or current. I want to know if that's what a transistor can be used for...

Comment: Transistors amplify signals. Depending on what type, they amplify either current or voltage, and you can add external components to control the degree of amplification.

Comment: @Felthry or anyone who can answer...          I might be a little extreme but I could amplify an Arduino 5V signal to 10V?      That' may or may not be the value I'm shooting towards, I just want to know how it would be possible. Or at the very least tell me the electrical engineering book/section to where I can learn it

Comment: From what you are describing, you would want to use the transistor as a switch.

Comment: Look up "motor driver" and "h-bridge" for examples.

Comment: @Spurlock With a properly designed circuit involving several transistors, you could amplify a 5V signal up to 10000V if you wanted. 5V to 10V is easy.

Comment: @Felthry thanks for the input. I guess the next thing is how to design one of those circuits. Anyone know a good place to start?

Comment: @Spurlock You could play around in something like falstad's CircuitJS, perhaps. (Or in real life, but it's harder to visualize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transistors allow you to switch and amplify voltage and/or current. If the motor driver is weak, you may be able to use the motor driver to drive the transistor which will switch the power rail voltage through the motor which may correct your power problems at the motor. A transistor on its own cannot increase voltage or current. It can only lower a voltage/current down to 0 from the maximum. So if your board is driven with a 5V power rail, you cannot get 10V out of it.

If you're interested in increasing voltage or current, you should look into switch mode power supplies which use either inductors or capacitors with transistors to alter the voltage/current ratio to better serve the load. Note that this doesn't increase power, it only changes voltage to the downside of current or vice/versa.

Also note that amplification of transistors isn't increasing the power of a signal, it's taking a signal and creating a transformed version of it using energy from the power rails.

To answer your question succinctly, a transistor is a switch controlled by another voltage/current.

Comment: I'll use this thanks, horta is it? I would upvote you, but the whole reputation minimum thing...

Comment: @Spurlock No problem. Let me know if anything is confusing and if this answers your question you can still mark this answer as the "solution".

Comment: I would use the term valve rather than switch.  For digital logic the valve is on or off.   In analog, want more current?  Open the electron valve by driving the transistor's base.  Where only a little current is required to proportionately open the valve to allow much more current through the collector emitter.